# How to remove ant-click-animating of button Ant design

Tags: css, antd

After I click on the button, it has the animation around the button. So I want to turn it off, I try to set CSS for element and Pseudo-classes but it's not working.

```
.ant-switch,
.ant-switch:focus,
.ant-switch:active {
  border-color: white !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline: unset;
}
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'antd';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const RSwitch = styled(Switch)`
  background-color: ${props => props.backgroundcolor};

  .ant-switch-handle::before {
    background-color: #9b9b9b;
    right: 0;
  }

  &[aria-checked='true'] {
    .ant-switch-handle {
      ::before {
        background-color: ${props => props.color};
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function SwitchComponent({
  onChange,
  checked,
  color = '#00afdb',
  backgroundColor = ''
}) {
  return (
    <RSwitch
      onChange={onChange}
      checked={checked}
      size="small"
      color={color}
      backgroundcolor={backgroundColor}
    />
  );
}
```

[ant switch picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l85xZ.png)

[HTML of switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0mpn.png)

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it with this solution
create a button.less file in your ant overrides and put this inside

`[ant-click-animating-without-extra-node='true']::after{display:none;}`

and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ant-btn {
        &::after {
            all: unset;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lifesaver! This has been driving me crazy and your answer is the only one that helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just if someone still searching for the correct working solution.
You should use ant ConfigProvider. You can wrap only one button or the entire application with it if you want to disable animation globally.

```
import { ConfigProvider, Button } from 'antd';
    
<ConfigProvider wave={{ disabled: true }}>
  <Button>My button</Button>
</ConfigProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is just a div tag so I don't display it. If everybody has a better solution, please let me know.

```
.ant-click-animating-node {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work bro. I'll post an answer in the next days.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue for one button like this.
`"antd": "^5.0.1",`

```
  .linkBtn {
    ...;
    &:focus {
      :global .ant-wave {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
```